# Understanding LUA Callbacks

Tags: lua, callback

For example this code:

```
-- Defining a function that takes a callback function as a parameter
function HelloMessage(callback)
  -- Below you are passing the string "sup" as a parameter to the callback function 
  callback("sup")
end

-- Here, below, we are calling the function defined earlier
-- and we pass a callback function to it (a.k.a. "handler") 
HelloMessage(function(message) 
  print(message) -- "sup" gets printed
end)
```

I did not understand how it works. How does it pass the sup into the message parameter??

Comment: [PiL](https://www.lua.org/pil/6.1.html)

Comment: I would suggest running and modifying the code here https://www.lua.org/cgi-bin/demo to experiment a bit ;) Cheers.-

Answer (score 1):

```
HelloMessage(function(message) print(message) end)
```

is basically equivalent to

```
do
  local callback = function(message) print(message) end
  callback("sup")
end
```

which is equivalent to

```
do
  local message = "sup"
  print(message)
end
```

`function(message) print(message) end` defines an anonymous function that is immediately referenced by the function argument `callback` which is a local variable in `HelloMessage`'s scope.

Answer (score 0):

```
cb_function = function( var_txt ) print("var_txt = ", var_txt ) end

function HelloMessage( callback_func )
  if type( callback_func ) == "function" then --just chek is func passed
     callback_func( "Print to callback function" )
  end
end

HelloMessage( cb_function ) --passing call back function
```